# Canvas image scroll performance in FF

Tags: javascript, performance, html, firefox, canvas

I am having a terrible performance issue in FF.

Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
var img = new Image();  
img.src = 'image.jpg'; 

var w = $(window).outerWidth();
var h = $(window).height();

var addit = -1;
var scrollSpeed = 10; //fast in IE, but very slow in FF
var current = 0;

ctx = document.getElementById('canvas1').getContext('2d');

var init = setInterval(function(){
        current += addit;
        ctx.drawImage(img,current,0, w, h);
           }, scrollSpeed);
```

**CSS:**

```
    #canvas1 {
        width:auto;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas1" width="1784px" height="534px"></canvas>
</body>
```

*image.jpg is 1784x534px*

Can anybody help me get the same performance in FF as IE?
I have tried to use CSS left property but performance is still slow.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some investigation into hardware acceleration; I noticed in Firefox "about:support" that "Direct2D Enabled" was blocked by a wrong version graphics driver.

I updated it, and now things are much faster thanks to hardware acceleration.